# Read Json file in JAVA with io.vertx.core.json library

Tags: java, json, vert.x, jsonparser

I want to read .json file in java and typecast it to JsonObject.Please suggest the code with Json but not JSON.I am using `io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject library` .

```
Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader()); //this is from library simple.ore.JSON.
JsonObject obj1;
obj1 = (JsonObject)(obj);
```

I tried to use JSONparser for file reader which gives JSONObject but i need JsonObject.

`java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be cast to io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject.`

Comment: See, you need to use either org.json.simple.JSONObject or io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject. both provider are different and on the other hand, class JsonObject 
extends Object
implements Iterable<Map.Entry<String,Object>>, io.vertx.core.shareddata.impl.ClusterSerializable, Shareable and public class JSONObject
extends java.util.HashMap
implements java.util.Map, JSONAware, JSONStreamAware, so you could see the difference.

Comment: For reference you could check - https://www.mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/ , https://www.codota.com/code/java/methods/org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser/parse

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you're using the parser from another library and expecting to get an instance of `io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject`. Instead, read your file containing your JSON text into a Java string. Note that you can do this using the [`IOUtils.toString(Reader)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toString(java.io.Reader)) method. Then, use the `JsonObject`'s constructor. For example, you could just use something similar to the following code:

```
String jsonStr = IOUtils.toString(new FileReader(myFileName));
JsonObject jsonObj = new JsonObject(jsonStr);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: also keep in mind that FileReader blocks the eventqueue, therefore vertx has own filesystem tools: vertx.fileSystem().readFile(...)